# Pentaho Spoon transformation throws: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP

Tags: oracle11g, etl, pentaho, transformation, spoon

Hey I'm doing a simple transformation with Pentaho Spoon, the transformation has two steps:

1. **Input table:** I use a SQL to extract the data from an Oracle 11g database.
2. **Excel Output:** I write the data from the database in an excel file.

The problem is when I try to run this 2 steps transformation, nothing is happening. I tried to visualize the first 200 entries from the first step but throws the following error:

*ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP.*

Is this the reason why the transformation doesn't work, how I could fix it, having into account that I don't have admin privileges into the database to increase the TEMP tablespace size.

These are the Loggin messages:

[image]

[image]

The query used in the input table method is as follows:

```
SELECT
ptn.ptnID,
ptn.ptnNAME,
ptn.ptnSURNAME,
ptn.SSN,
ptn.EXTERNALID,
ptn.NTS,
ptn.GENDER,
ptn.DOB,
ptn.ADDRESS,
ptn.CITY,
ptn.STATE,
ptn.COUNTRY,
ptn.POSTALCODE,
ptn.ACTIVE,
ptn.NACIONALITY,
ptn.COUNTRYOFBIRTH,
ptn.EXITUS,
ptn.ptnFIRSTSURNAME,
ptn.ptnSECONDSURNAME,
ptn.DEATHDATE,
appl.applID,
srv.srvDESCRIPTION,
center.CENTERDESCRIPTION,
appl.applLABEL,
appl.applDATE,
appl.COMPLETEDATE,
container.COMMENTS,
sample.SAMPLEDESCRIPTION,
test.TESTDESCRIPTION,
test.UNITSCS,
rslhst.RESULTSTATUS,
rslhst.ISAUTOMATIC,
pathology.PATHOLOGYDESCRIPTION,
FROM USRGR.APPLICATION appl
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.PTN ptn on ptn.ptnid = appl.ptnid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.APPLICATIONTEST appltest on appltest.ptnid = appl.ptnid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.TEST test on test.testid = appltest.testid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.RSLHST rslhst on (rslhst.applid = appltest.applid) AND (rslhst.testid = appltest.testid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.CONTAINER container on container.containerid = rslhst.containerid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.DOC doc on doc.docid = appl.docid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.SRV srv on srv.srvid = appl.srvid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.CENTER center on center.centerid = srv.centerid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.SAMPLE sample on  sample.sampleid = container.sampleid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.CLTRISOL  cltrisol on  cltrisol.applid = rslhst.applid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.ISL isl on isl.islid = cltrisol.islid
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.PATHOLOGY on pathology.pathologyid = rslhst.pathology
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.COD cod on cod.codsfamilyid = rslhst.codsfamilyid AND rslhst.shortdescription1 = cod.shortdescription
LEFT OUTER JOIN USRGR.INTERVALS intervals on intervals.testid = test.testid AND intervals.methodid = rslhst.methodid
WHERE
    appl.orderdate BETWEEN '01/01/19' AND '02/01/19' AND
    rslhst.isfinal = 'Y' AND
    appl.iscomplete = 'Y' AND
    ((to_number(to_char(appl.ORDERDATE, 'YYYY')) - to_number(to_char(ptn.DOB, 'YYYY'))) * 12 * 12 >= intervals.from) AND
    ((to_number(to_char(appl.ORDERDATE, 'YYYY')) - to_number(to_char(ptn.DOB, 'YYYY'))) * 12 * 12 < intervals.to) AND
    test.testid in (
    5, 5261,
    435, 438,
    5014, 3986, 3987,
    4293, 6017, 2295, 2296, 2298,
    196, 199, 218, 219, 1626, 3861, 5275, 5276
    );
```

Explain Plan output:

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"

"Plan hash value: 3813514414"

" "

"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

"| Id  | Operation     | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost  | "

"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                  |   319K|   497M|       |  1508K|"

"|*  1 |  FILTER           |                  |       |       |       |       |"

"|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER |                  |   319K|   497M|   494M|  1508K|"

"|   3 |    VIEW           |                  |   319K|   490M|       |  1500K|"

"|*  4 |     FILTER        |                  |       |       |       |       |"

"|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER|                |   319K|   172M|   148M|  1500K|"

"|*  6 |       HASH JOIN OUTER|               |   319K|   145M|   140M|  1491K|"

"|*  7 |        HASH JOIN OUTER|              |   319K|   137M|   116M|  1489K|"

"|*  8 |         HASH JOIN OUTER|             |   319K|   112M|   105M|  1487K|"

"|*  9 |          HASH JOIN OUTER|            |   319K|   101M|    88M|  1485K|"

"|* 10 |           HASH JOIN OUTER|           |   284K|    85M|    79M|  1483K|"

"|* 11 |            HASH JOIN OUTER|          |   284K|    76M|    74M|  1482K|"

"|* 12 |             HASH JOIN|               |   284K|    71M|   148M|  1481K|"

"|* 13 |              FILTER|                 |       |       |       |       |"

"|* 14 |               HASH JOIN OUTER|       |   669K|   141M|   121M| 89111 |"

"|  15 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER|   |   669K|   114M|       | 87134 |"

"|* 16 |                 HASH JOIN OUTER|     |  1616 |   257K|       | 22494 |"

"|* 17 |                  HASH JOIN OUTER|    |  1616 |   211K|       | 22479 |"

"|* 18 |                   HASH JOIN OUTER|   |  1616 |   173K|       | 22474 |"

"|* 19 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| APPLICATION |  1616 |   123K|       | 22469 |"

"|  20 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| SERVICE     |   292 |  9344 |       |     3 |"

"|  21 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| CENTER      |    16 |   384 |       |     3 |"

"|  22 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| DOC         |  7154 |   202K|       |    12 |"

"|  23 |TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| APPLICATIONTEST|414 |  6624 |    |    40 |"

"|* 24 |INDEX RANGE SCAN| RQTEST_PTNID_IDX    |   414 |       |       |     3 |"

"|  25 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TEST        |  4292 |   176K|       |    31 |"

"|* 26 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | RSLHST      |   187M|  7686M|       |  1233K|"

"|  27 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PATHOLOGY   |    45 |   720 |       |     3 |"

"|  28 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | COD         |  4289 |   142K|       |    14 |"

"|  29 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | CLTRISOL    |   212K|  4144K|       |   505 |"

"|  30 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | ISL         |  2303 | 80605 |       |     6 |"

"|  31 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | CONTAINER   |   674 | 53920 |       |     5 |"

"|  32 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SAMPLE      |   354 |  9558 |       |     2 |"

"|  33 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PTN         |  1886K|   160M|       |  3887 |"

"|  34 |TABLE ACCESS FULL       | MARGINS     |  2232 | 49104 |       |     8 |"

"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation is performing a sort or creating a temporary data set for a join that requires TEMP space. Depending on your transformation and the explain plan of the query, it might not even matter if you limit the number of rows you are returning if the transformation must process all of the source data before applying your filter. It is very likely that the only way to get this to run is to increase the size of the TEMP tablespace. You will need to work with your DBA to confirm this and work out a solution.

Comment: Hey, I just added the query used in the first step of the transformation, is there anything that I could change to don't have this problem?

Comment: With that many joins I suspect there isn't much you can do. Can you also post the explain plan for the query, with as much detail as possible? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-explain-the-explain-plan-052011-393674.pdf

Comment: Also, if you can, any details from the dba_data_files view for the TEMP tablespace...

Comment: How I should post the explain plan, I just exported it in HTML but I can't attach it into the post due to the character's limitation. Is there another way to post the explain plan instead of HTML?

Comment: There should be a way to export/generate it as plain text.

Comment: I just added it, viewing the TempSpc numbers is there any way to make them decrease ?

Comment: You want to get rid of the full table scans, if possible. In general, make sure all of your join columns are indexed, and that you have current statistics collected for all objects in the schema, then check the explain plan again. The number of joins is going to make this difficult, because Oracle is having to build intermediate data sets to get the final product and isn't applying most filters until the end of the process.

Comment: I used this command: SYS.user_ind_columns  to view all the indexed columns and I don't have anyone. How I should create them?

Comment: SQL tuning is a bit of an art. See here to get started: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/how-do-i-learn-to-tune-sql. This may require cooperation with your DBA, and the creation of new database objects.